# Multilateral shift operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Apparently, the operators

$u(e_n) = e_{n+1}$

and

$u^\ast (e_n ) = e_{n-1}$

are called "unilateral shift oeprator".

Since they have to be called that (instead of calling them "the shift operator") I am wondering what the other types of shift operators are. I am struggling to come up with a definition for a multilateral shift operator.

What other shift operators are there?

Answer (score 0):

The unitary shift operator on $l^{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ is not unilateral. This operator is the same as multiplication by $e^{i\theta}$ on $L^{2}[0,2\pi]$ with normalized inner product
$$
              (f,g) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(\theta)\overline{g(\theta)}\,d\theta.
$$
You can see this because every $f \in L^{2}[0,2\pi]$ can be written as the orthogonal sum
$$
                       f = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}(f,e^{in\theta})e^{in\theta}.
$$
The unilateral shift is multiplication by $z$ on the Hardy space $H^{2}(D)$ consisting of all holomorphic functions $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n z^{n}$ in the unit disk $D$ such that
$$
                    \|f\|^{2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_n|^{2} < \infty.
$$
Another common type of shift is a weighted shift where
$$
              e_{n} \mapsto \lambda_n e_{n+1}.
$$